# Парсер HTML

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, html, парсер

Здравствуйте. Я написал парсер для данного сайта: http://olx.ua/nedvizhimost/prodazha-kvartir/ (НЕ РЕКЛАМА)

```
ignore_user_abort(1);

$content = file_get_contents('http://olx.ua/nedvizhimost/prodazha-kvartir/');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// <table id="offers_table" class="fixed offers breakword" summary="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">BLALDKALSDKLASKLDSADASDASD</table>

$file = preg_match_all('<table id=\"offers_table\" class=\"fixed offers breakword\" summary=\"\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">(.*)<\/table>', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Собственно, он не работает. Мне нужно так, чтобы при добавлении нового обьявления высылалось письмо на почту. Я думаю, что можно просто каждую минуту парсить и сравнивать первое объявление со старым "первым объявлением", записаным в переменную. Но не суть. Главное, что данный код выдает это:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown
> modifier '(' in
> E:\Work\OpenServer\domains\teststealer.alex\script.php
> on line 10 NULL

Помогите с решением.

Comment: В моём ответе кончились комментарии :)  
Новые определять можно по разному - возможно в коде есть какая-то метка (дополнительный класс, атрибут особый...), если нет - парсить и проверять на наличие новых объявлений (спарсил `1,2,3`, через время спарсил `1,2,3,5` - методом сравнения нашёл новое - `5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыл крайние символы, например `!RegExp!`.
Вот рабочее:

```
$file = preg_match_all('!<table id=\"offers_table\" class=\"fixed offers breakword\" summary=\"\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">(.*)<\/table>!', $str, $arr);
```

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо. Еще одно - почему-то не парсит. Ну вот хоть убейся, var_dump: 1 -> {}, 2 -> {}

:(

Comment: @Alex_Wells, вопрос неясен - что не парсится-то?  
Не скачивается сайт?

Comment: Тот же код, просто, не выводит ничего. Ну, то есть, var_dump выводит это:

    array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Проверь что в `$str`, там должен быть исходный код.  
Если его нет, то понятно, почему массив пуст.  
Если в `$str` лежит код - кидай побольше и поточнее кода, ибо тот, что ты кинул - проходит проверку: https://regex101.com/r/aU5tU3/1

Comment: Собственно, лежит. Просто в примере забыл. Я скопировал HTML код с сайта, вставил на тот regex-тестер, что ты скинул, и он не подошел :C

На этой странице есть <table> с объявлениями, так вот, мне нужно их спарсить. Почему не работает-то?

Comment: Изучил я сорцы.
  
Ты, видимо, даже не подумал изучить его:
  
1. `caption` бывает (и часто) не пустой.    
2. К `class` добавляется ещё один класс, рандомный, после `breakword`.    
3. Может, ещё что-то, я не пристально изучил, время поджимает.
  
Позже напишу с учётом... особенностей.

Comment: Так, посмотрел, нахватал глюков и вот:

    <table\s+width="100%"\s*cellspacing="0"\s*cellpadding="0"\s*class="fixed\s+breakword\s+.*\s*" summary=".+"\s*>\s*([\d\D]*?)<\/table>!img

Понятия не имею почему, но модификатор `m` послал меня нах и пришлось его заменить на аналог.  
Так код страницы парсится (хотел скинуть линк, но их сайт упал, так что проверяй сам).

Comment: Да, это уже парсится. Спасибо большое! Но... как сделать так, чтобы данная хрень слала мне на почту именно новые объявления? То есть появилось объявление, и сразу же мне на пошту уведомление с ссылкой. Возможно такое? Знаю, что дофига хочу, но я же не прошу готового кода... намек =)

И еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используй лучше библиотеку `simple_html_dom.php`, чтобы парсить сайты, там никаких регулярок не нужно, за тебя уже всё придумали!

```
http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=639
```

Comment: Я это видел и пробывал, но я так и не разобрался, как отпарсить именно то, что мне нужно =(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
$file = preg_match_all('!<table id=\"offers_table\"[^>]+>(.*?)<\/table>!', $str, $arr);
```

Comment: Нет, ничего.